# Enforce Compile Time Detection of Code Contracts in VB.NET Project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, code-contracts, compile-time, static-code-analysis

I'm trying to setup [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148151.aspx) in a VB.NET project.

Here's a real simple method that should ensure that the passed in divisor argument is not zero:

```vb
Public Function Divide(ByVal numerator As Integer, ByVal divisor As Integer) As Double
    Contract.Requires(Of ArgumentOutOfRangeException)(divisor <> 0, "Divide By Zero Not Allowed")
    Return numerator / divisor
End Function
```

If I call `Divide(5, 0)`, I should get a compile time error. But alas, I don't:

[image: demo]

I've downloaded the  Add-In from the **[Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970)**.
I have static code analysis enabled on the *Code Contracts Property Page*:

[image: PropertyPage]

This works when I follow the same steps in C#:

[image: working]

What else could be missing?

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with "CodeContracts" but I will give this a try.

It ***may*** be because you are Dim'ing something, but are dividing it in the same line, so "CodeContracts" may think that, "Oh, this line is Dim'ing something, move on to next line."

By this I mean, that the "CodeContract" is looking for an actual line of code that is just dividing. For example:

```
result = 5 / 0
```

***Instead of:***

```
result = Divide(5, 0)
```

This could also just be, the technique in which you are dividing, but keep in mind, I have never worked with "CodeContracts" before, so this may be way off, **but hopefully this helps!**